# How to write a 2 decimals value in the same statement?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am struggling with giving the value with 2 decimals

i want to give the float value with only 2 decimals but i can't do it in the same line:

```
birth_rate = float(input("What is the birth rate of data point?"))
```

like if i add the %.2f it keeps giving me an error

Comment: Show us the actual input you used, and the full error message.

Comment: Try: `birth_rate = f'{float(input("What is the birth rate of data point?")):.2f}'`

Comment: Or `birth_rate = round(float(input("What is the birth rate of data point?")),2)`